# Not understanding the solution of exercise 2.39 in Mendelson.

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

This question is from "[Introduction to Mathematical Logic](https://www2.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/%7Ekrajicek/mendelson.pdf)" by Elliot Mendelson , fourth edition.

At page $83$ , I was given the following theorem to prove at exercise $2.39$:

> $\vdash \lnot (\exists y)(\forall x)(A^2_1(x,y) \leftrightarrow \lnot A^2_1(x,x))$

After some tries I gave up proving , so I looked up the solutions in the book . Here is the solution of the book (page 390):

1. $\vdash (\exists y)(\forall x)(A^2_1(x,y) \leftrightarrow \lnot A^2_1(x,x))$  [Hype]
2. $(\forall x)(A^2_1(x,b) \leftrightarrow \lnot A^2_1(x,x))$ [1,rule C]
3. $(A^2_1(b,y) \leftrightarrow \lnot A^2_1(b,b))$ [2, rule A4]
4. $\mathscr C \land \lnot \mathscr C$ [3 , tautology]

($\mathscr C$ is any wf not containing $b$.) Use Proposition $2.10$ and proof by contradiction.$\square$

But there are soe places I didn't understand at all.

1. When applying rule A4 to line 2 , shouldn't it be $(A^2_1(b,b) \leftrightarrow \lnot A^2_1(b,b))$ instead of $(A^2_1(b,y) \leftrightarrow \lnot A^2_1(b,b))$
2. I have no idea how the book derived line 4 from line 3.

Comment: step 3 is wrong... it must be: $A(b,b) ↔ ¬A(b,b)$

Comment: Having said that, abbreviating the contradiction $C \land \lnot C$ with $\bot$, we may use Lemma 1.11(c): $\lnot B \to (B \to \bot)$ with bi-conditional elimination (pag.78): $A(b,b) ↔ ¬A(b,b), ¬A(b,b) \vdash A(b,b)$.

Comment: Understood my 1st confusion , but still didn't understood how **proof by contradiction** (page 78) was used for proving this theorem.

Comment: Having derived from assumption 1 the contradiction $C \land \lnot C$, we conclude with not-1 by Contradiction (page 78).

Comment: I think by tautology in line 4 they mean the tautology $(B \leftrightarrow \lnot B) \to (C \land \lnot C)$. Right?

Comment: It is the same... The result is obvious; if you want a formal proof, you have to write a step-by-step derivation according to the rules of Mendelson's system.